# How to get session driver Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-5.5

How I can get current session driver used for session in Laravel 5? 
I want to know where my session is written.
I can get session ID using

```
Session::getId();
```

but driver can't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello you can get next

```
Session::getDefaultDriver();
```

For more info about methods visit [Laravel API](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Session.html)

Answer (score 0):

Or simply in a controller:

`dd(session()->getDefaultDriver());`